# How to query Azure Active Directory as an end user

Tags: active-directory, azure-active-directory, office365

I can connect to our legacy company DOMAIN and query Active Directory.  This has been my way to get the membership of groups.

We've added Office 365 and I cannot find the new groups added via Office 365 Groups (ie, Teams, etc) in Active Directory.

Is this a thing I should be able to do as an end user?  And it so, how?

My preference (and what I've been using) is to Query via Power Query
(IE Excel->Data->Get&Transform->Get Data->From Other Sources->From Active Directory)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

•   As an end user, you have the default permission to view the groups and its members in an Azure AD tenant so, you can use the Microsoft Graph API explorer to view the groups and its related details in that console.

•   Here is the link to access the Microsoft Graph Explorer - https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer. You will have to login with your credentials in it and enter the below query with ‘GET’ parameter as set to get the list of all groups available in your tenant.

‘GET [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups’](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups%E2%80%99) – Please find the below screenshot for more details.

[image: Microsoft Graph Explorer]

•   Please find the below links for more information: -

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/users-default-permissions

Comment: This is great, thanks.  Just fyi.  No Power Query support https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/connecting-to-graph but at least they're open about it.

Comment: Yeah, thank you for the document. Thought the Microsoft Graph method would be helpful for you. Didn't know you had a dependency for Powerquery.